# Change text size of an attributed text in TextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uifont

Here I try to repaint text due to the color scheme - day/night which I do successfully , but I fail to add different text size same way - I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". fontSize is not null, it's a float, so it doesn't crash there

```
public static func processAttributedText(text:NSMutableAttributedString?) -> NSMutableAttributedString?{
    var sPref = SharedPreferences()

    if let text = text{
    let textAttributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: isNight() ? background_light : background_night
    ]
        let fontSize = sPref.getTextSize()
        let font = UIFont (name: "roboto", size: CGFloat(fontSize))! //Here where the error is
    let fontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName : font
    ]
    text.enumerateAttributesInRange(NSRange(0..<text.length), options: []) { (attributes, range, _) -> Void in
        for (attribute, object) in attributes {
          if let textColor = object as? UIColor{
                if (!textColor.isEqual(Utils.greyColor) && !textColor.isEqual(Utils.redColor)){
                    NSLog("found our attr")
                    text.setAttributes(textAttributes , range: range)
                }                                        
            }
            if  let _ = object as? UIFont {
               text.setAttributes(fontAttributes, range: range)
           }

        }
    }
    }
    return text
}
```

Comment: you're sure that it's on the line you have marked? It seems weird that your trying to unwrap a `UIFont` declaration.

Comment: It could be crashing when you use the result from `processAttributedText`.

Comment: no, it's the right line. I figured that it doesn't recognized "roboto" font , although it's in Info.plst

Comment: Can you add some breakpoints and check to see if it's nil after initializing?